# Operador '==' no se puede aplicar a los operandos del tipo 'grupo de métodos' y 'int'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy intentando lo siguiente para filtrar en la vista, pero me arroja error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group'
>   and 'int'

Codigo donde me lanza el error:

```
@if (Model.BariatricVisits.Where(p=>p.IsActive==true).Count == 0)
```

Código completo:

```
@model Domain.MED.Bariatric

   @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Historia Bariatrica";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }


   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

   <div class="form-horizontal">

   @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PatientId)
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BariatricId)


  <div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("CreatePediatricVisits", 
  "Patients", new { area = "Medicals", id = @Model.PediatricId })"> 
  <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>   Registrar Visita</a>


@if (Model.BariatricVisits.Where(p=>p.IsActive==true).Count == 0)
{
    <h2>No existen Visitas Pre Quirurgicas registradas aun :'(</h2>
}
else
{
  //..
}
```

Comment: verifica el codigo nuevamente hermano,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error indica que el operador `==` no se puede utilizar comparando un metodo con un valor `int`. El método `Where` retorna un `IEnumerable` y la interfaz no tiene una propiedad Count, sino un método de extension [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count(v=vs.110).aspx).

Reemplaza `Count` por `Count()`:

```
@if (Model.BariatricVisits.Where(p=>p.IsActive==true).Count() == 0)
{
\\...
}
```

Comment: excelente, muchas gracias, eso resolvio el error, despues le aplique el refactor de ReSharper y me arrojo el siguiente resultado, para que lo tengas en cuenta para otros casos

 @if (Model.BariatricVisits.All(p => p.Type != true))

Comment: O mejor aun: `Model.BariatricVisits.All(p => !p.Type)`

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta dada por Einer es la correcta, luego use el refactor de ReSharper y me arrojo la siguiente forma

```
 @if (Model.BariatricVisits.All(p => p.IsActive!= true))
{
....
}
```

Comment: es que usa el bucle .all

Comment: Si la propiedad IsActive es booleana, ni siquiera es necesario hacer la comparación ('==' ó '!='). Con solo referenciar la propiedad debe de ser suficiente. @if (Model.BariatricVisits.All(p => !p.IsActive))